# Use of ternary operators as function parameter

Tags: dart

I was here wondering if there is any difference between

- calling a function with the ternary operator as parameter:

```dart
functionResult = someFunction(someFlag ? paramA : paramB);
```

- and defining the parameter before and then call the function:

```dart
functionResult = someFlag ? someFunction(paramA) : someFunction(paramB);
```

Could be any performance differences between these two? If not, what would be the preferable way to do it?

Comment: Any performance difference would be negligible.  An optimizing compiler would probably produce the same code for the two.  To ME, the first one seems better because it has less repetition, but that's a personal preference.

Comment: @TimRoberts oh yeah, I hadn't thought about the compiler, but that really makes sense. Thanks Tim!

Comment: You can also choose the function in a ternary expression, which is quite neat: `functionResult = (someFlag ? functionA : functionB)(param)`